# Ng-route makes unwanted requests

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Whenever I change a route, my app sends two unwanted GET request to the server. One fetches favicon and another one index.html file.

[image]

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngTagsInput']);
 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
   resolve: {
    async: ['$http', function($http) {
     return $http.get('/api/getUserInfo');
    }],
    dialogs: ['$http', function($http) {  
     return $http.get('/api/dialogs'); 
    }]          
   },
   controller: 'ProfileController'
   })
  .when('/friends', {
   template: '<div friends-directive votes="model.user.votes" friends="model.friends"></div>'
  })
  .when('/comment', {
   template: '<div comment-directive></div>'
  })
  .when('/dialogs', {
   template: '<div dialog-directive messages="model.messages" dialogs="model.dialogs" new-messages="model.newMessages"></div>'
  })
  .when('/messages', {
   template: '<div messages-directive messages="model.messages"></div>',
   resolve: {
    async: ['$http', function($http) {
     return $http.get('/api/message'); 
    }]
   },
   controller: 'MessagesController'
  })
  .when('/search', {
   template: '<div search-directive></div>'
  })
  .when('/balance', {
   templateUrl: 'views/balance.html'
   })   
  .when('/users/:username', {
   template: '<div users-directive user-profile="model.userProfile" switcher="switcher(path)" resource="model.resource"></div>',
   resolve: {
    async: ['$http', '$route', function($http, $route) {
     return $http.get('/api/users/' + $route.current.params.username); 
    }]
   },
   controller: 'UsersController' 
  })  
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
 }]);
 
 app.run(['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
  var update = function(){
   $http.get('/updatetime')
  };
  setInterval(update, 60 * 1000);
  
  $window.onload = function() {
   update();   
  }
 }])
```

```html
<base href="/">   

<aside id="aside">
 <div><a href="/"><img src="images/profile.svg"></a></div>
 <div><a href="/friends"><img src="images/users.svg"></a></div>
 <div><a href="/search"><img src="images/search.svg"></a></div>
 <div><a href="/balance"><img src="images/database.svg"></a></div>
 <div><a ng-click="logout()"><img src="images/help.svg"></a></div>
</aside>
```

I just noticed these unwanted requests. Everything else works okay. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: I didn't have favicon.ico file on my server. That's it!